# Log4j2 not working when OSGI is started from console (Works in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, osgi, log4j2

I had a logging program made using log4j2 up and running on eclipse. I am not using any xml file for the configuration, rather I am programmatically modifying the default configuration. And I am developing in OSGi environment using declarative services.

When I run OSGi from console, and start the logger bundle, there is no error. But when ever I start another bundle that is consuming the service of this logger bundle, an error is displayed showing:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.NamingException
```

I put the entire error log down here in case it gives detailed information. As a result the bundle will not resolve. What could be the cause of this problem?

```
!SESSION 2014-08-21 23:05:27.381 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -console -consoleLog

!ENTRY comp4 4 0 2014-08-21 23:07:16.979
!MESSAGE [SCR] Error while trying to bind reference Reference[name = ILogger, interface = de.logger.ILogger, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = bindLoggerService, unbind = unbindLoggerService]
    Details:
    Problematic reference = Reference[name = ILogger, interface = de.logger.ILogger, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = bindLoggerService, unbind = unbindLoggerService]
    of service component = comp4
    component implementation class = de.comp4.finalTest
    located in bundle with symbolic name = comp4
    bundle location = file:\C:\Users\test2\plugins\comp4_1.0.0.jar
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bind(ServiceComponentProp.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:75)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:99)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:80)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:473)
    at de.logger.tinylogger.TinyLogger.setClassName(TinyLogger.java:1097)
    at de.comp4.finalTest.bindLoggerService(finalTest.java:27)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.NamingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:75)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:99)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:80)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:473)
    at de.logger.tinylogger.TinyLogger.setClassName(TinyLogger.java:1097)
    at de.comp4.finalTest.bindLoggerService(finalTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bind(ServiceComponentProp.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.NamingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more

!ENTRY comp4 4 0 2014-08-21 23:07:17.006
!MESSAGE [SCR] Error while trying to bind reference Reference[name = ILogger, interface = de.logger.ILogger, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = bindLoggerService, unbind = unbindLoggerService]
    Details:
    Problematic reference = Reference[name = ILogger, interface = de.logger.ILogger, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = bindLoggerService, unbind = unbindLoggerService]
    of service component = comp4
    component implementation class = de.comp4.finalTest
    located in bundle with symbolic name = comp4
    bundle location = file:\C:\test2\plugins\comp4_1.0.0.jar
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bind(ServiceComponentProp.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:75)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:99)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:80)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:473)
    at de.logger.tinylogger.TinyLogger.setClassName(TinyLogger.java:1097)
    at de.comp4.finalTest.bindLoggerService(finalTest.java:27)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.NamingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:75)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:99)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:29)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:80)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:72)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:473)
    at de.logger.tinylogger.TinyLogger.setClassName(TinyLogger.java:1097)
    at de.comp4.finalTest.bindLoggerService(finalTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ComponentReference.bind(ComponentReference.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bindReference(ServiceComponentProp.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.bind(ServiceComponentProp.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:800)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.NamingException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2014-08-21 23:07:17.037
!MESSAGE The component was not built because some of its references could not be bound. The component is Component[
    name = comp4
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = true
    implementation = de.comp4.finalTest
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = null
    references = {
        Reference[name = ILogger, interface = de.logger.ILogger, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = bindLoggerService, unbind = unbindLoggerService]
    }
    located in bundle = comp4_1.0.0 [18]
]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2014-08-21 23:07:17.041
!MESSAGE The component was not built because some of its references could not be bound. The component is Component[
    name = comp4
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = true
    implementation = de.comp4.finalTest
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = null
    references = {
        Reference[name = ILogger, interface = de.logger.ILogger, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = bindLoggerService, unbind = unbindLoggerService]
    }
    located in bundle = comp4_1.0.0 [18]
]
```

Edited:

I have tried it in a simple setup just using LogManager.getLogger() with no configuration code(left to be default) but still the result is the same. The bundle containing Log4j2 only resolves if I did not call the method containing "LogManager.getLogger()".

```
....Inside logger...
private static Logger m_Logger;
public void setClassName(String className) 
    {
    //Logger m_Logger = LogManager.getLogger(className); 
    Logger m_Logger = LogManager.getLogger(); 
    m_Logger.error("Logger program working");
    }
....Inside consuming bundle...
protected void OSGiLoggerBind (OSGiLogger myLogger)
    {
    m_LoggerService = myLogger;
m_LoggerService.setClassName(OSGiLoggerTest.class.getName());
    }
```

Comment: I have just checked if I could call LogManager.getLogger() and it worked for me. Could you please provide a sample (your environment packaged into a zip or a code snippet of log4j initialization) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have tried it by removing all initializations but it is still the same. I first get the instance of the bundle containing Log4j2 and then call a method that executes LogManager.getLogger(). Have you used the same approach?

Comment: As much as I understand, it fails on calling the static method LogManager.getLogger(). I called it as well in an equinox environment that was started from the command line. The static method call worked well and the log appeared. That is why I am asking if you can package a sample that fails.

Comment: I couldn't find an option to put the sample package on stackoverflow. That's why I edited the main question with a snippet of the code. Have you seen the portion of the code I added?

Comment: @BalazsZsoldos I have noticed from the link here [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-373?jql=project%20%3D%20LOG4J2%20AND%20component%20%3D%20Core%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20created%20ASC) that there is a bug in Log4j2 having a classloader issue when embedded inside another bundle in OSGi. May be you have a working jar. Could you please give me the link where you got your Log4j2 jars? And how many jar files you have? Thank you!

Comment: I added version 2.0.2 from maven central with two other ow2 dependencies to satisfy its imported packages. If you embedded the log4j jar, the problem might be that you imported the necessary package with "resolution:=optional" so the missing requirement did not turn out at the time that the bundle was started but only when the class was actually used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a bug. LOG4J2 had classloader issues in OSGi environment as in [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-373) and also similarly [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-477).

I was previously using the download version apache-log4j-2.0-rc2-bin. 
But now there is a new release [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html) apache-log4j-2.0.2-bin and it runs under OSGi environment. But for the bundle with LOG4j2 to resolve correctly, I had to import "org.osgi.framework.wiring".

It still shows me the error "Could not reconfigure JMX java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/management/ObjectName...." and I still need to find a solution for it, but at least it runs in OSGi environment which is started from console.